# Can the cohomology group $H^1(H, E[p])$ be trivial for all subgroups $H$ of $Gal(K(E[p])/K) \simeq GL_2(\mathbb Z/p)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-cohomology

Let $p$ be a fixed odd prime, $K$ be a number field and $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $K$. Set $L =K(E[p])$.
We know that $G=Gal(L/K)$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb Z/p)$.

Suppose $G =GL_2(\mathbb Z/p)$, is it possible that $H^1(H, E[p])$ is trivial for all subgroups $H$ of $G$?

Comment: The question in the body differs from the one in the title (and the former doesn't even really seem to be a well defined question).

Comment: For the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$, the $H^1$ is trivial only if $p$ were allowed to be $2$.

Comment: For $K=\mathbb{Q}$ the question is related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186807/for-an-elliptic-curve-e-mathbbq-can-the-cohomology-group-h1-textgal-m/186836, which inspired Tyler Lawson and me to write an article.

Comment: [Lawson and Wuthrich - Vanishing of some Galois cohomology groups for elliptic curves](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-45032-2_11) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3629657)).